# Extract table from HTML using pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am working with python 2.7 on Windows 10 and I am using the Spyder IDE. I'm trying to extract a table from the following link:

http://www.espn.com/nhl/statistics/player/_/stat/points/sort/points/year/2015/seasontype/2

using pandas. My code reads:

```
import pandas as pd
import html5lib

url = 'http://www.espn.com/nhl/statistics/player/_/stat/points/sort/points/year/2015/seasontype/2'
table = pd.read_html(url)
```

but I get the error message that the html5lib module is not installed. I have installed it using pip, but even after restarting Spyder, I still get the message

```
ImportError: No module named html5lib
```

I have looked everywhere and no solution seems to work for me: unistalling and installing html5lib, updating pip, updating anaconda3, etc. Can anyone help me?

EDIT

Through the Command Window in Spyder I used

```
easy_install html5lib
```

and now, running pip list, html5lib (1.0b10) appears, but I still get the same message: ImportError: No module named html5lib.

Comment: Does running `pip list` from the Spyder console show `html5lib`?

Comment: Doing pip list on the Cmd (Windows command prompt) it does show html5lib (0.999999999). However, on Spyder, going to Tools > Open command prompt and typing pip list, I actually don't find html5lib.